# Revise existing Levenshtein distance code to accommodate different operation costs

Tags: c++, levenshtein-distance

I have found a lot of sources that determine Levenshtein distances (LD) between two strings. However all of them assume the costs for substitution, insertion, and deletion operations are all set to 1.

This [source](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#C.2B.2B%20source) for C++ is very efficient, which I am trying to adapt below to allow different costs per operation.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

size_t levenshtein_distance(const std::string &a, const std::string &b);

int main()
{
    std::string a, b;

    a = "roger"; b = "Roger";
    std::cout << levenshtein_distance(a, b) << std::endl;

    a = "roger"; b = "oger";
    std::cout << levenshtein_distance(a, b) << std::endl;

    a = "oger"; b = "roger";
    std::cout << levenshtein_distance(a, b) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

size_t levenshtein_distance(const std::string &a, const std::string &b)
{
    // Costs of operations
    const size_t substitution = 5;
    const size_t deletion = 2;
    const size_t insertion = 2;

    size_t a_size = a.size(), b_size = b.size();

    std::vector<size_t> P(b_size + 1), Q(b_size + 1);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < Q.size(); i++)
        Q[i] = i;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < a_size; i++)
    {
        P[0] = i + 1;

        for (size_t j = 0; j < b_size; j++)
            P[j + 1] = std::min(
                std::min(Q[j + 1] + 1, P[j] + 1), Q[j] + ((a[i] == b[j])? 0: substitution));

        P.swap(Q);
    }

    return Q[b_size];
}
```

I think I have `substitution` in the correct place. If I change it to 5, it gives a correspondingly large LD for that operation, but can't seem to find where to apply `insertion` or `deletion`. I tried changing the literals `1`, but they don't seem to have any effect - the result is always 1 for the insertion or deletion operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adapt the algorithm from wikipedia as following:

```
size_t levenshtein_distance(const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2)
{
    const size_t substitution = 5;
    const size_t deletion = 2;
    const size_t insertion = 3;

    const size_t len1 = s1.size(), len2 = s2.size();
    vector<vector<unsigned int> > d(len1 + 1, vector<unsigned int>(len2 + 1));
    d[0][0] = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= len1; ++i) d[i][0] = deletion * i;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= len2; ++i) d[0][i] = insertion * i;

    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= len1; ++i)
        for(unsigned int j = 1; j <= len2; ++j)
            d[i][j] = std::min(
                std::min(d[i - 1][j] + deletion, d[i][j - 1] + insertion),
                d[i - 1][j - 1] + (s1[i - 1] == s2[j - 1] ? 0 : substitution)
            );
    return d[len1][len2];
}
```

For example `d[i][0]` means the cost of transforming the first `i` characters of first string to the zero first characters of the second string. This comes obviously from deletions and so `d[i][0] = deletion * i`. Similarly, `d[0][i] = insertion * i`.

If you don't want to use the two dimensional array, then you can only keep the last row:

```
int levenshtein_distance(const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2)
{
    const int substitution = 5;
    const int deletion = 2;
    const int insertion = 3;

    const int len1 = s1.size(), len2 = s2.size();
    std::vector<int> P(len2 + 1), Q(len2 + 1);
    for(int j = 1; j <= len2; ++j) P[j] = insertion * j;
    for(int i = 1; i <= len1; ++i) {
        Q[0] = deletion * i;
        for(int j = 1; j <= len2; ++j) {
            Q[j] = std::min(Q[j - 1] + insertion, P[j] + deletion);
            Q[j] = std::min(Q[j], P[j - 1] +
                (s1[i - 1] == s2[j - 1] ? 0 : substitution)
            );
        }
        std::swap(P, Q);
    }
    return P[len2];
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid the 2-D vector? i.e. Do it efficiently in a single column?